Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant) using SizedBox(width:)
I want to set dynamic width to SizedBox to differentiate between iPhone & iPad
double forgotPasswordBtnWidth = 0.00;

    child: Row(
               children: [
               const SizedBox(
               width: forgotPasswordBtnWidth),//Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)

  Future<bool> isIpad() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    IosDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    if (info.model.toLowerCase().contains("ipad")) {
      forgotPasswordBtnWidth = 850;
      return true;
    }
    forgotPasswordBtnWidth = 700;
    return false;
  }
}

Getting error - Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)
SizedBox(width: forgotPasswordBtnWidth) - forgotPasswordBtnWidth

Can you suggest the fix that how to set dynamic value to SizedBox width
Thanks In Advance

remove const before SizedBox

here is the correct code
double forgotPasswordBtnWidth = 0.00;

    child: Row(
               children: [
               SizedBox(
               width: forgotPasswordBtnWidth),//remove const

  Future<bool> isIpad() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    IosDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    if (info.model.toLowerCase().contains("ipad")) {
      forgotPasswordBtnWidth = 850;
      return true;
    }
    forgotPasswordBtnWidth = 700;
    return false;
  }
}

You need to is because u want is being set forgotPasswordBtnWidth  dynamically, but you're trying to use it as a constant in a widget tree.
Basically, Dart constants must be known at compile-time, in your case forgotPasswordBtnWidth is determined at runtime based on device information.
